# Video post doesn't showing on my Page after published by Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem publishing my video on Facebook. I'm building a web application (API), I implemented Facebook Graph API docs to publishing video on a Facebook Page. Everything work fine, but if someone on Facebook visits my Page, they don't see the post, video isn't show with them. The post is set public mode, not limit everyone. I have raised a question, is that access token generated from Graph API Explorer only supports for testing user? Has anyone answered this question for me?

Comment: Have you taken the app live?

Comment: @WizKid Not yet, my dashboard page is not complete, so Facebook doesn't approve for me the permissions I need

Comment: That is the reason.

Comment: @WizKid so, the access token I get from Graph API Explorer can not publish with everyone? If that's the case, I should tell the leader about that.

Comment: Yes you can publish using that one. But only developers of the app will see the posts until the app is LIVE